# GPG decryption in AWS Lambda error code 2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda (in python, although my problems are probably not python-related) that will, among other things, decrypt a PGP file stored in S3.

I have a script that runs fine locally (on an ubuntu machine).  I have adapted the relevant parts of that script into the lambda script.  I'm using python-gnupg, and have created a layer to get to that functionality.

I created a CentOS VM on that ubuntu machine, and put gpg on that.

I have a deployment zip that I think is correct (contents are the script, bin/gpg, lib/{libgpg-error.so.0,libreadline.so.7,libcrypt.so.20,libassuan.so.0}; the gpg executable and libraries are all from that CentOS VM).  If I, for instance, remove libassuan from that, I do get an error about that being a missing dependency, hence my believing that the zip is correctly created.

When I deploy the lambda, the code shows up correctly and seems to run (I did have to set it to use the python-gnupg layer, of course).

This is still in basic testing, so the file I'm trying to decrypt is the same one I used on the ubuntu box test, and is being retrieved from S3.  The decryption key and passphrase are being retrieved from AWS Parameter Store and are, as near as I can tell, being retrieved correctly (the latter is definitely correct; the former is the correct length with the correct start and correct end).  And I do not get an error adding the key (not sure if I would, I guess).

So, everything looks right, coming in.  Getting to the decryption itself, we have:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=f"{targetDir}/..", gpgbinary="./bin/gpg")
key_data = open(keyFileName, 'rb').read()
priv_key = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
decrData = gpg.decrypt_file(contents, passphrase=pgpPassphrase, always_trust=True, extra_args=[ '--yes' ])
if not decrData.ok:
    logger.error (f"decryption failed: {decrData.status}")
```

As I implied earlier, this fails with error code 2, and the printed status message is 'decryption failed'.  Totally unhelpful.

Unsurprisingly, the decrData object has zero data.

FWIW, always_true and extra_args, as shown, did not change anything (nor did passing both as extra_args=[ '--yes', '--always-trust' ]).  I was getting exactly the same results before adding those.

So, all that being said, the question is, does anyone have any suggestions on something I might have done wrong, or what else I can check to see why I'm getting this error?

Thanks.

**Update**:
Ok, I made a mistake here.  I did not have this working, locally; I had a different version (using PGPy) working locally.

Testing locally yesterday, I figured out that my problem was that the key wasn't being imported successfully.  The root of that seems to've been that the key was in the wrong format (binary, sent in as uuencoded in the Parameter Store).  So I re-exported the key, adding the argument '--armor' to the 'gpg --export-secret-keys' command, then added 'passphrase=...' to the gpg.import_keys() call, and that worked locally (at least to get the key imported; I actually haven't checked the gpg.decrypt() or gpg.decrypt_file() command.

However, taking that exported key and putting it into the Parameter Store... It looks like I am getting it back from the parameter store correctly (I've checked the beginning, the ending, and spots in the middle - including where I joined the two parameters from the Parameter Store), but the key is still not being imported correctly when I run my lambda.  FWIW, I did try adding "extra_args=[ '--yes', '--always-trust']" to the gpg.import_keys(), which did nothing.  I also tried uploading the key file to S3, and getting it back from there, which also did nothing.

Again, I welcome any suggestions for other things to try.

Thanks again.

**Update 2**: I also tried supplying the key file (ascii-armored) as part of the distribution zip.  That kind-of worked (though I did have to put the key file into a subdirectory; leaving it at the top level led to a permissions problem on the main python file, somehow), in that the file was there, and seemed to be read correctly.  However, the key still failed to import.

I seem to be stuck where I was with the PGPy solution, where the code worked perfectly, when run locally, but not when I ran it in AWS.

**Update 3**: Finally did run my local test to completion and, as expected, the file decrypted perfectly.  Wish I knew why I can't import the key on AWS.

Comment: You shouldn't need an extra Lambda layer - why don't you just package it with the zip? And does the code all work fine locally?

Comment: I tried putting the python stuff into the same zip, and it wasn't found.  Since I had previously created the layer, it was easier to just connect the layer than to figure out why it wasn't found (but just in case, it was in a directory called 'python', same as it had been for the layer zip).

Comment: And yes, it worked fine locally

Comment: The Python file needs to be at the root - create a new directory, add your script to it, `cd` into the directory & then run `pip install --target ./ python-gnupg` from inside. Zip then upload and then try again.

Comment: Just for grins, I moved the python-gnupg stuff up from the python directory to the root, and removed the layer reference.  That still ran, but with identical results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to add here.

Part of why I had gotten confused about testing locally was that I had gotten it running under the Python 3.7 runtime (which has GPG as part of the VM).  So that's a partial answer.

I was trying to get it running under 3.9, though, to be current.  I had tried to solve this via a Docker image.  I created the image, but, for terrible reasons, was unable to deploy it.  So that's why I was trying via a deployment zip.

As I mentioned, I was using a version of GPG (and attendant libraries) that was pulled off a CentOS VM.  This did get closer than my previous attempt, which had used GPG/libraries from Ubuntu.  That had fallen apart on libc version.

What finally occurred to me today, though, was that maybe I could pull apart my Docker image, and grab GPG/libraries from that.  Using 'docker save --output="filename.tar" image-name', I was able to dump the files out, so I sifted through that to get the relevant files and create a new deployment zip.

The short of it is that that worked perfectly.